# what is the difference between LIKE and REGEXP?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL wildcard query that isn't working probably because I use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.category_id FROM products a 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid=a.ownerid 
WHERE a.active=1 AND a.approved=1 
AND a.deleted=0 AND a.name LIKE '%*my*%' 
AND a.name LIKE '%*donuts*%' 
AND (a.name REGEXP '( )*(*my*)*( )*(*donuts*)( )*')
```

It works fine whenever a word is used instead of a wildcard, that's not the problem.

I'm just wondering, is the part of

```
(a.name REGEXP '( )*(*my*)*( )*(*donuts*)( )*')
```

really needed after already doing a

```
LIKE '%*my*%' AND a.name LIKE '%*donuts*%'
```

What is the difference?

Comment: `'( )*(*my*)*( )*(*donuts*)( )*'` -- it is very strange regular expression. I bet the author of this expression have no idea how to write regexes

Comment: "I have a mySQL wildcard query that isn't working probably because I use InnoDB instead of MyISAM." --- no it doesn't work because both `LIKE` and `REGEX` expressions composed incorrectly

Comment: You might be better of just showing us your goal (e.g. what you are looking for) and asking help as to how to do this, because I'm not really sure above does what you think it does...

Comment: The error mySQL returns is: Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp - that means that both LIKE and REGEX are doing the same thing, right?

Comment: No, that means a repetion operator (`*` in this case) has an invalid operand (maybe the empty group `()` ?

Comment: replace the last regexp with '( )*(\\*my\\*)*( )*(\\*donuts\\*)( )*', then it may make sense considering the _like_ wildcard patterns preceding it

Comment: I'll try that and will contact the developer, thank you very much :)

Comment: What exactly are these conditions supposed to catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference?

- **The regular expression**

  ```
  (a.name REGEXP '( )*(*my*)*( )*(*donuts*)( )*')
  ```

  This produces an error, because a quantifier (e.g. an unescaped `*` character) is not valid at the start of a group (i.e. immediately after an unescaped `(` character).  Ignoring the two times where that occurs yields:

  ```
  (a.name REGEXP '( )*(my*)*( )*(donuts*)( )*')
  ```

  This matches any `a.name` with:

  1. zero or more spaces, followed by
  2. zero or more occurrences of:

     - the letter `m`, followed by
     - zero or more letters `y`

     followed by
  3. zero or more spaces, followed by
  4. the character sequence `donut`, followed by
  5. zero or more letters `s`, followed by
  6. zero or more spaces
- **The simple pattern**

  ```
  a.name LIKE '%*my*%' AND a.name LIKE '%*donuts*%'
  ```

  This matches any `a.name` with:

  1. any sequence of characters, followed by
  2. the character sequence `*my*`, followed by
  3. any sequence of characters

  **and** with:

  4. any sequence of characters, followed by
  5. the character sequence `*donuts*`, followed by
  6. any sequence of characters